# Java OpenCV save video file

Tags: java, opencv

I would like to save a file (avi) of some frames (in this case, 600) from my webcam using java opencv, but i have no idea how to do that, the code below gives me the avi file specified but with size 0, no frames inside whatsover, also in the directory i have those 600 frames in jpeg's.

It's important to use java for that, no python.

```
 Mat frame = new Mat();
    VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter("c:/opencv/vid.avi", VideoWriter.fourcc('X','2','6','4'), 30 ,frame.size(), true);

    videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
    videoCapture.open(0);

    videoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    videoCapture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);

    while (true){
        videoCapture.read(frame);
        if (!frame.empty())
            break;
    }

    int frameNo = 0;
    while (frameNo < 600){

        videoCapture.read(frame);
        writer.write(frame);
        Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();
        String file = "c:/opencv/i" + frameNo + ".jpg";
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(file,frame);
        frameNo++;
    }

    videoCapture.release(); // release device
```

Comment: In your second line you specified your video sizes as ```frame.size()``` what is frame, how did you initialize it. That sizes should be equal to resolution(width and height) which is desired video size.

Comment: Your code arrangement seems to need re-arrange and the initialization of the frame is also looks to have problem which @YunusTemurlenk also mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which openCV version are you using, I use OpenCV-3.4.2

AVI container use DIVX codec reference: https://wiki.videolan.org/DivX/

I modify a bit your code:

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter("c:/opencv/vid.avi", VideoWriter.fourcc('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), 30, new Size(videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
while(runnable)
{
    if(videoCapture.grab())
    {
        try
        {
            //Decodes and returns the grabbed video frame.
            videoCapture.retrieve(frame);
            //encode to .jpg the frame to a MatOfByte
            Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", frame, mem);
            //read into an Image
            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
            //Draw image to a Jpanel
            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
            Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null);
            //record the frame
            writer.write(frame);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
videoCapture.release(); // release device
```